# JMF and RTP Protocol

Tags: java, jmf, rtp

I am doing a project which consists of a video-conference system in Java and using the RTP protocol.  The problem is that I can not pass the stream to the clients, that I capture in my webcam.  I already turned off my firewall, but still it does not work.

Someone can give me a hand?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Stack traces? Specific errors you are encountering? Currently you give no way of helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the network traffic, e.g. with Wireshark.